# Slow Contact Search and Message Forwarding in WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I'm facing noticeable delays when using WhatsApp on my Samsung Galaxy A30s. This issue particularly affects searching for contacts and forwarding messages.

The problem manifests in two scenarios: (1) when searching for a contact to start a new conversation, and (2) when trying to forward a message from one chat to another. In both cases, the process can take an unusually long time, sometimes up to two to three minutes.

I have attempted basic troubleshooting steps such as restarting WhatsApp and the device, clearing the huge chats, and updating the app to its latest version, but these actions haven't resolved the issue.

I am seeking advice on how to address or minimize these delays. Is this a common issue with specific resolutions, or are there particular settings I might need to tweak?

My phone is a Samsung Galaxy A30s. The WhatsApp version is 2.23.24.82.

Any insights or assistance with this matter would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: May I know the number of contacts on the device? Also, does the issue also happen on other apps that look up contacts? I wonder if there may be a corrupted contact inside the Android centralized contacts database.

Comment: About 1,500 contacts. As far as I see, the issue is unique for WA.